# Can't find the 'open in browser' option when r-clicking on default.aspx

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

Something strange is going on for me.

I can open the web application on my desktop computer just fine, where it opens the asp.net MVC application with a URL like http://localhost:5118/ when I rigth click on the default.aspx file and choose `'open in browser'`.

**On my laptop, I don't have that option when I right click on default.aspx for some reason (it should give me the option to Open in Browser).**  I set the project as a web application, but it still doesn't work.

This is a vs.net MVC application.

I want to open the application without having to setup a IIS site for it.

Comment: Is this inside or outside of the IDE?

Comment: inside the IDE, right clicking on the default.aspx file I am looking for the 'open in browser' option.

Comment: Just press F5 or CTRL-F5 - that should fire up the Visual Studio webserver with the default page.

Comment: Dan, F5 worked, it asked me to modify the web.config to allow for debugging.  strange how my other computer doesn't have these issues?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have what option on your laptop?  Can you be a bit more clear?

Also, make sure your hosts file has:
127.0.0.1   localhost

-- this is advice from another site --

Can you see it under the File option while current page is aspx page? Shortcut key of "View in Browser" is Ctrl+Shift+W.

You can try to run "devenv /resetsettings" from Visual Studio command to reset settings.

You also can try to run "devenv /resetuserdata" to reset Visual Studio to its out-of-box state.

Comment: when I right click on default.aspx, I don't have that option to open in browser.

Comment: So you're missing 'view in browser?'

Comment: I tried the devenv /resetsettings and still don't see the 'open in browser'option.